# SwiftUI List with custom data structure with nested for each loops

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have been able to successfully implement infinite scroll in my swiftui application but it doesn't behave correctly and it has to do with the list it iterates over. For example, I get a list of product orders from a graphql endpoint and its stored as

```
@Published var groupedPurchaseOrders = [[PurchaseOrderFragment]]()
```

The reason it is nested in an array is because I process this data into groups separated by order date.

```
func groupPurchaseOrders() {
        
    let dateGroups = Dictionary(grouping: purchaseOrders) { (element) -> Date in
        return element.orderForDate.reduceToMonthDayYear()
    }
      
    let sortedKeys = dateGroups.keys.sorted { (Date1, Date2) -> Bool in
        Date1 > Date2
    }
        
    sortedKeys.forEach { key in
        let values = dateGroups[key]
        groupedPurchaseOrders.append(values)
    }
}
```

This way I can create a list that has headers with a date (which I derive from the first item in the list) then the purchase order.

```
ForEach(posModel.groupedPurchaseOrders, id: \.self) { group in         
    Section(header: <Derived date from first item>) {
        ForEach(group, id: \.self) { order in
            NavigationLink(destination: PurchaseOrderDetailView(purchaseOrder: order)) {
                PurchaseOrderListItemOnlyView(purchaseOrder: order)
                    .padding(.vertical, 4)
                    .onAppear {
                         let purchaseOrders = posModel.groupedPurchaseOrders.flatMap { $0 
                         if purchaseOrders.last == order {
                              self.loadOrders()
                         }
            }
        }
    }
}

Date
    Order
    Order
Date
    Order
    ...
```

**The Problem**:

The list loads the first 20 items fine, but when it gets to the bottom of the list and loads more (in this instance, 5 more items) it adds the 5, the list has the original 20 plus 25. But when I create a normal list without the grouping it works as intended and just appends the 5 to the end.

As a beginner with ios dev, Im not sure if I can create a data structure like
[Date, [PurchaseOrderFragment]] as apposed to [PurchaseOrderFragment]. I've have tried it but just can't seem to get the syntax and implementation right... Any ideas on how to implement the list with the grouping? where it appends the records correctly?

**EDIT**:

I have tried

```
struct GroupedOrder: Hashable {
    var date: Date
    var orders: [PurchaseOrderFragment]
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(date)
        hasher.combine(orders)
    }
}
```

and it still duplicates the list when it loads 5 more

Comment: You *could* make a tuple with a type `(Date, [PurchaseOrderFragment])`, but it seems like it would make more sense to just make a wrapper: `struct PurchaseWrapper { var date: Date; var orders: [PurchaseOrderFragment] }` and then iterate over those.

Comment: @jnpdx I did exactly that and it just duplicates the first 20 with the added 5 on the load more. Do you think it might be a limitation of the List component?

Comment: No -- it has to do with your `groupPurchaseOrders` function. All you ever do is `append`. I don't think you have enough information/code here to diagnose what the logic *should* be, but you'd need to determine whether or not you need to replace the whole array, append to certain elements of it, etc.

Comment: In the list there is 45 elements, but printing out the count of the list in the model, it has 25, seems to be in the List

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? Otherwise it's impossible to help debug specifics.

Comment: Of course, I will be able to soon

Comment: Turns out there is nothing wrong with the List but there is with me... I found the error in the grouping function that kept getting the whole list every call, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a playground based on your code.  What it is missing is the concept of "loading 5 more" that your code doesn't show.  But the grouped dates is simply formed from the same `Dictionary(grouping: purchaseOrders) { $0.date }` as your original code.  Theoretically you could use any list of purchase orders with that.
`

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

let mockPurchaseOrders = """
[
    { "date" : "1/1/2020", "title": "The First Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "1/1/2020", "title": "The Second Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "1/1/2020", "title": "The Third Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "3/2/2020", "title": "The Fourth Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "3/2/2020", "title": "The Fifth Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "5/1/2020", "title": "The Sixth Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "7/1/2020", "title": "The Seventh Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "7/1/2020", "title": "The Eighth Purchase Order" },
    { "date" : "7/1/2020", "title": "The Ninth Purchase Order" }
]
"""

struct PurchaseOrder : Decodable, Hashable {
    static var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter;
    }()

    let title : String
    let date : Date

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Self.CodingKeys)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.title)

        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        date = PurchaseOrder.dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!

    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case date
    }
}

typealias GroupedDates = [Date : [PurchaseOrder]]

struct NestedListView : View {
    let groupedOrders : GroupedDates
    var orderDates : [Date] { Array<Date>(groupedOrders.keys).sorted() }
    static var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter;
    }()

    init(orders : GroupedDates) {
        groupedOrders = orders
    }

    var body : some View {
        ForEach(orderDates, id: \.self) { date in
            Section(header: Text(NestedListView.dateFormatter.string(from: date))) {
                ForEach(groupedOrders[date]!, id: \.self) { order in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello!")) {
                        Text(order.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 320, idealWidth: 320, maxWidth: 320, minHeight: 480)
    }
}


let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let purchaseOrders = try jsonDecoder.decode([PurchaseOrder].self, from:  mockPurchaseOrders.data(using: .utf8)!)
let groupedOrders = Dictionary(grouping: purchaseOrders) { $0.date }

let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: NestedListView(orders: groupedOrders))
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = hostingController
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, very much appreciated, but I found that in the set grouping function I was getting the whole list again hence the duplication, but I learned a lot from your example on how to reimplement it I will check it as the answer

Comment: Whoops!  I guess I missed your comments about a hour before I posted my solution!  I appreciate the kind words and I'm happy this could help you learn.